# Django: How to change package name in PyDev

Tags: python, django, eclipse

I have PyDev installed and configured correctly. I create a new Djaango project as follows
- I start Eclipse 
 
- I create a new Eclipse workspace: C:\project\django-workspace
- I set the interpreter to Python 2.7
- I create a new PyDev Django Project by going through the wizard
- I name my new project 'demos'
- PyDev creates a demos project and a 'demos' PyDev Package (which I think is the same as an app)
- I run the app and everything works well

Now I'm just trying to rename the PyDev Package (or app) from 'demos' to 'prototype'
- I right click on Demos package and click rename and enter prototype

When I run the app now I get:

```
raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
```

ImportError: Could not import settings 'demos.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named demos.settings

on other threads, users have suggested that the problem is that the project and app are named hte same which causes the problem... well in my case, it seems that the opposit is correct. Once I rename the app, I get this error. When the app and the project are named the same everything seems to work as expected? I've battled this problem for the last two days, any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I have just experienced the same problem and the solution was to set the *Django settings module* in the project properties. Right click on the project, then click *Properties*, go to *PyDev - Django* and set the *Django settings module* text field's value to the desired settings file.